# handleEvent method in EventListener interface not implemented in the implementing class

Tags: java, event-listener

`EventListener` interface declares `handleEvent(Event evt)` method, and in the code below `GeneratorListener` extends that interface. I am told this code is correct. BUT I don't see why Printer class **does not have to** implement `handleEvent` method? Isn't it the case that all the methods in an interface must be implemented?

```
public interface GeneratorListener extends EventListener {
    void objectGenerated(String object);
}

public class Printer implements GeneratorListener { 
    public void objectGenerated(String object) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide code for EventListener

Comment: that is java provided interface, I believe.

Comment: Is it compilable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I know the answer.
Method

```
public void handleEvent(Event evt);
```

is contained in org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener.
But in your GeneratorListener interface you probably imported java.util.EventListener that looks like

```
package java.util;

/**
 * A tagging interface that all event listener interfaces must extend.
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public interface EventListener {
}
```

So your Printer class implements the only abstract method that you have in Printer class hierarchy. That's why your code is correct.